# How do I discover the lowest negative possible CGFloat?

Tags: constants, swift3, cgfloat

I know of these values:

- `CGFloat.infinity`, which is greater than
- `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`, which is greater than
- `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`, which is greater than
- `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`, which is greater than
- `0`

but it stops there... as far as I can tell. Where are the negative values? I imagine maybe it's as easy as placing a `-` before them, but then I worry that there might be strange exceptions.

**How do I find the key negative numbers in CGFloat?** Critically, the lowest negative non-infinite number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Floating point numbers have a sign bit and negating them changes this sign bit to the opposite value (there is actually a negative zero).

Just put a minus before them. The negation is well defined.